# Capture a temporary file?

Tags: windows

I'm having trouble compiling a library on Windows using Visual Studio, and I want to inspect a temporary file that's being used. Visual Studio does not appear to have an option to save or copy the file I'm interested in.

**Question**: How do I capture a temporary file that's written and immediately deleted?

The background information is on Stack Overflow at [LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file - what file is corrupt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443752/lnk1107-invalid-or-corrupt-file-what-file-is-corrupt) and [Capture Visual Studio response file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451431/capture-visual-studio-response-file).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the permissions on the directory where the directory where the temporary file is created to deny delete permissions.  This way the the file will be created, but Visual Studio will not be allowed to delete it.

To set the deny delete permission you'll have to go into the advanced security settings for the folder since the basic dialog doesn't give you granular enough control.

[image]

Comment: Ugly hack (lots of Visual Studio noise due to failed deletes), but it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Similar problem here. I had to deny "Delete subfolders and files", but it worked. Thanks.